# Azure Function with Timer Trigger and sql input binding

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I would like to pass the azure sql input binding where my sql command is a select statement with a parameter. This does not work. It keeps telling me the 'complete' is not a parameter. What am I doing wrong or is what I'm trying to do impossible with sql input binding? When I have a simple statement like select top(10) id, status from Dispatch - it works. Can I not pass a string to the parameters?

```
[FunctionName("Function1")]
public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 */2 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer,
[Sql("select top(10)id, status from Dispatch where status = @critstatus; ",
CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text,
Parameters = "@critstatus= {'complete'}",
ConnectionStringSetting = "SqlConnectionString")]
IAsyncEnumerable dispatch, ILogger log)
```

or

```
[FunctionName("Function1")]
public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 */2 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer,
[Sql("select top(10)id, status from Dispatch where status = \''complete\'' ",
CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text,
ConnectionStringSetting = "SqlConnectionString")]
IAsyncEnumerable dispatch, ILogger log)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to get the parameter to work so for now I was able to get the timer to work with the azure sql input binding.

```
public async Task  Run([TimerTrigger("0 */2 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer,  
            [Sql("select top(10)id, status, arrivaldate from Dispatch where  
                 status = \'in progress\';" ,
                 CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text,
                 ConnectionStringSetting = "SqlConnectionString")]
                 IAsyncEnumerable<Dispatch> dispatch, ILogger log)
            {

                IAsyncEnumerator<Dispatch> enumerator = 
                           dispatch.GetAsyncEnumerator();
                   var dispatchList = new List<FindDispatch>();
            while (await enumerator.MoveNextAsync())
            {
                dispatchList.Add(enumerator.Current);
            }
            await enumerator.DisposeAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

**According to this [MSFT Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings?tabs=csharp#supported-bindings), Your SQL Query is not bindable as input to the Timer trigger as we have tested in our local environment.**

***Supported Input Bindings for the Azure Function Timer Trigger:***
[image]

***To fetch the data by giving input parameters for every 2 min (Timer Trigger) in Azure Function, we can call the SQL Query String inside the Run Method Code.***

**Function 1.cs:**

```sql
        public void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */2 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
           
            string connString = "Server=<yourservername>,1433;Initial Catalog=samplesqldb0808;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=<username>;Password=<password>;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;";


            //Query to fetch data
            string queryString = "SELECT TOP 2 Id, Status FROM [dbo].[Dispatch] WHERE Status = 'Complete';";
            
            //Connection
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", "Complete");
                connection.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                try
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        log.LogInformation(String.Format("{0}, {1}", reader["Id"], reader["Status"]));
                        
                        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}",
                        reader["Id"], reader["Status"]));// etc
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    // Always call Close when done reading.
                    reader.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

***Created Sample data in the database with below SQL Query:***

```sql
CREATE  TABLE dbo.Dispatch (
[Id] int  primary  key,
[Status] nvarchar(200) not  null
)
```

```sql
INSERT  INTO Dispatch (Id, Status)
VALUES
(571, 'Pending'), (572, 'Complete'),
(573, 'InProgress'), (598, 'Complete'),
(593, 'Complete'),(581, 'Complete'),
(597, 'InProgress'), (596, 'Pending');
```

[image]

**Result:**

***I could see the results in the console for both of the methods Logging and Console WriteLine:***
[image]